# Remove space before decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am a bit new to regex. I want to convert examples such as `hello coffee 0 .08 - 0 .24%` to `hello coffee 0.08 - 0.24%` (removal of space before decimal and ignore other situations). Can you please suggest a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
for my_str in ['hello coffee 0 .08 - 0 .24%', 'hello coffee 0. 08 - 0. 24%']:
    my_str = re.sub(r'(\d)\s*([.])\s*(\d)', '\\1\\2\\3', my_str)
    print(my_str)
# hello coffee 0.08 - 0.24%
# hello coffee 0.08 - 0.24%
```

Comment: Can you please also suggest for `coffee 0. 08 - 0. 24%` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-regex solution:

```py
word = 'hello coffee 0 .08 - 0 .24%'
new = []
print([str(num) for num in range(10)])
for c, char in enumerate(word):
    if char == ' ':
        if word[c+1] == '.' and word[c+2] in [str(num) for num in range(10)]: #if followed by a decimal point and next char is a number
            new.append('')
        else:
            new.append(char)
    else:
        new.append(char)
print(''.join(new))
```

Comment: I don't want to use replace. It doesn't check for decimal, it will replace all instances of `' .'` with `'.'` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
txt = 'hello coffee 0 .08 - 0 .24%'
txt = re.sub('0 \.', '0.', txt)
print(txt)
```

hello coffee 0.08 - 0.24%